# Download specific files from github in command line, not clone the entire repo

Tags: git, github

How do I download just 2 files from github using command line ?
Something in the lines of :

```
git fetch git://github.com/username/Project.git/file1
git fetch git://github.com/username/Project.git/file2
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you go to the page and view the links provided by "raw" (in the top left corner, when viewing the file). You will see, that you can access it by:

```
https://github.com/username/repository/raw/$changeset_hash/path/to/file
```

Instead of `$changeset_hash` you can also provide a branch (e.g. master) or tag.

You can retrieve the raw file using something like wget.

Accessing a single file directly from a .git-repository is not possible (as far as I know), because of how the data is stored.

**edit:** When you want to access a file from a private repo, you first have to create an access token with the appropriate permissions in your account settings. Instead of calling the url above you can then use [github's API to access the content of a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents). Be sure to use the Accept-header for [custom media types](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types) to get the raw data. This might look something like this:

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: token $YOUR_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
  -O \
  -L 'https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path'
```

The `-O` will save the contents in a local file with the same name as the remote file name. For easier use you can wrap it in a script. @Chris_Withers suggested an edit with a nice python snippet that unfortunately got rejected as to big of a change to the answer.

Comment: Accessing a single file from .git is fairly straightforward.  git ls-tree branch gives a list of the files and/or trees.  Then git cat-file -p blob-sha prints the contents of a file.

Comment: How can I get it from private repo ?

Comment: I also want something from a private repo, so I must send authentication first.  A simple CURL or request won't work, due to authentication problems.

Comment: You can create an access-token and add it to the curl-request's authentication-header.

Comment: Great! Is there a possibility to further hide this Token on the local machine?

Comment: This no longer works :(

Answer (score 40):

Copy the specific file's raw link from GitHub.(As you open the file in Github, on the top right corner you can see the option to open the file in raw mode. Open it in raw mode and copy the URL)

Now use `curl` or `wget` command in command line to download the file.

```
curl -o filename raw-link-to-file
```

or

```
wget -O filename raw-link-to-file
```

Please note that

Comment: As of July 2023 this creates the object but inside it there is only `404: Not Found`

Answer (score 12):

In new UI interface(about June 2020), if your file url is

```
https://github.com/StellarCN/scp_zh/blob/master/fonts/SimHei.ttf
```

then

```
wget https://github.com/StellarCN/scp_zh/blob/master/fonts/SimHei.ttf?raw=true
```

Comment: Tried this just now (2023) and got a file with "?raw=true" at the end of the name. Tried without the param (just pointing at the blob link) and got a github payload rather than the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout
```

E.g:

```
git checkout master~2 file1
```

(`git checkout --help` for help)

Answer (score 3):

Need get raw link

```
curl https://github.com/[user]/[package]/blob/master/package.json
```

and than call to link like

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[package]/main/package.json
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [github-files-fetcher](https://github.com/Gyumeijie/github-files-fetcher), it is a command line tool which downloads a single folder or file from a GitHub repo.

Given the example above, you can use the following command to fetch the two specific files from github:

```
fetcher --url="git://github.com/username/Project.git/file1" 
fetcher --url="git://github.com/username/Project.git/file2"
```

Think a more real scenario: you were visiting the following webpage page and wanna download the `async` subdirectory alone.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples

> sorry for not being allowed to post images.

With The `github-files-fetcher`, you should first copy the `url` of that page, which is https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async, and then run the command below in command line:

`fetcher --url=https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async`

Answer (score 0):

**Plenty of great answers**, so I combined them into a lil script:

[GithubFileDownloader.sh](https://gist.github.com/electblake/7ef3a63e20b3c8db67d9d66f7021d727)

Instructions and such are in file but basically:

1. Download [GithubFileDownloader.sh](https://gist.github.com/electblake/7ef3a63e20b3c8db67d9d66f7021d727)
2. `chmod +x ./GithubFileDownloader.sh`

Bonus step is to rename and place in $PATH like

```bash
mv GithubFileDownloader.sh /usr/local/bin/gh-dl
```

- Uses Github CLI (`gh`), `curl` and `jq`
- The file url is the simple one (not raw) you'd get while browsing any github.com repositry file, for example: https://github.com/github/docs/blob/main/README.md

**Example Usage**

```
$ ./GithubFileDownloader.sh https://github.com/github/docs/blob/main/README.md
File downloaded successfully: README.md

$ cat README.md | head -2
# GitHub Docs <!-- omit in toc -->
[![Build GitHub Docs On Codespaces](https://github.com/codespaces/badge.svg)](https://github.com/codespaces/new/?repo=github)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using linux here it worked for me

Step 1 go to the file that you want to download and click on raw button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/endsj.jpg)

Step 2 copy the url from search bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpA2e.jpg)

Step 3 run the command in your terminal

```
wget paste-url
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVvpU.jpg)

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you. Also, sum up your answer in case the link stops working in the future.