# Storing Jupyter Notebook Files Online So They Can Be Between Multiple Computers

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm wondering what the most effective way to store .ipynb notebook files online is so they can be edited between multiple computers.

To clarify, what I'm looking for is something equivalent to overleaf, where all your files are stored online and they can be edited by whichever computer you are using. One possibility I was thinking about was using google drive and storing the files there- then accessing them somehow using jupyter notebook. Does anyone have any recommendations/do this already? I don't know how to access google drive files using jupyter.

Comment: Have you tried to use **git**?

Comment: Are you referring to github?

Comment: Jupyter Hub 
(https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub) might be what you're looking for!

Comment: @AntonvBR has a good suggestion

Comment: @LukePolson git is the system behind github, bitbucket etc. It is how you store, update and manage programming files.

Comment: So on git you can store .ipynb files and edit them from multiple computers? Thats all I need so I guess I'll go with that!

Comment: @AntonvBR git seems pretty overkill for what I'm looking for after reading some of its purposes.

Comment: Use a gist instead of full git repo. You can upload the gist to github (either through web or using terminal) and then use multiple computers. You can also choose to make it private or public (-p flag in terminal).

Comment: Expanding on fhobrrin's suggestion, you can also just use GitHub repositories directly with the web interface as well. Without using git at all. Then you can use `curl` or `wget` to get the raw notebook file as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159969/8508004) (or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48587645/8508004) where I talk about 'bring the script in as a file' at the bottom of section 1 and do that for the raw notebook file). Or `git clone` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742572/8508004) to get the entire repository from GitHub proper or a Gist.