# import a github into jupyter notebook directly?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

Hey Im creating a jupyter notebook, would like to install:

https://github.com/voice32/stock_market_indicators/blob/master/indicators.py
which is a python program

not sure how to do it directly so anybody that dowloads the notebook can just hit "Run All", and see the results

option 1) do something like:
from https://github.com/voice32/stock_market_indicators/blob/master/indicators.py
import indicators.py

of course this doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

You can clone the repository from your jupyter notebook using bash. Run in your cell:

```
%%bash
git clone https://github.com/voice32/stock_market_indicators
```

This will clone the stock_market_indicators repository to your directory.

You will now be able to access the functions in your indicators.py file. You can import it by running in jupyter:

```
%load stock_market_indicators/indicators.py
```

Comment: Couldn't find program: 'bash' . any suggestions to installed from notebook?

Comment: maybe some other command besides bash? seem that windows can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I got here searching for the same solution. Here is how I handled it through a Jupyter Terminal. I am using a Chromebook with Amazon SageMaker to host my Jupyter environment.

In the terminal, I used basic git commands (please excuse my mess)
[image: JupyterTerminal]

I had a sqlite database file that was 300mb so I added it to my [.gitignore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vejzukmn4s) file. I then uploaded the 300mb database directly to the same directory as my git clone using the upload function in Jupyter.

I found a cool Chrome Extension, [Keep Awake](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keep-awake/bijihlabcfdnabacffofojgmehjdielb/related?hl=en), that allows your computer to sleep but maintain internet if that helps anyone. Now that git has been initiated and my 300mb sqlite database is on my AWS cloud computer I can code on my Chromebook anywhere and push/pull commits.

Hope this helps!